# Changed boot settings in msconfig.exe and now Windows 7 doesn't boot

Tags: windows-7

I have a HP-G62 B17S laptop, which has Windows 7 Home Edition 64-bit.

I read on a blog about a setting in msconfig.exe (Windows System Configuration utility):

> Boot > Advanced options > Number of Processors

This was showing 1 for me but I have a dual core AMD Turion, so I changed the setting to 2. Next to it was a Maximum Memory setting (which was unchecked). I checked it and made sure it was max 4096; my system has 4GB RAM.

After restarting the laptop, it now gives an error:

> Windows Error Recovery
>   Windows failed to start

I can choose from two options:

1. Launch Startup Repair
2. Start Windows normally.

When I select Startup repair, it goes on to give another error:

> **Windows Boot Manager**
>   
>     Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
>
> 1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
> 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
> 3. Click "repair your computer."

I do not have the Windows installation disc for this OS version - the manufacturer did not send it to me when I purchased the laptop.

If I try to start Windows normally it takes some time and then gives the same error message.

I tried inserting another installation disc of Windows 7 Professional Edition 64-bit (available from my other laptop), and restarting, but no repair menu comes up.

I also tried restarting the laptop, pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> to enter Advanced Startup Options and selecting to boot with the *Last known good configuration*, or starting in safe mode - neither option gives any success. This time it gives a Blue Screen of Death with the following message:

> A problem has been detected, and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer - BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO

It then does a crash dump of the memory and restarts with the same options of repairing or starting Windows normally as earlier.

1. What exactly seems to be the problem here and its cause?
2. What are my options now to restore/repair my Windows 7 OS to a working condition? Would the manufacturer send a recovery/repair disk for this if I called them? The laptop should be in warranty period - it was purchased six months ago.
3. I have a Ubuntu 10.04 bootable CD. Is there any way to boot into Ubuntu, and repair Windows from there?
4. Are there any other way to recover the OS? (I have an access to a working Windows Vista HP Laptop, if that helps)

**EDIT Ok, it was able to boot through the Win-7 professional Installation disc, but even after doing Startup repair, and System restore, It still does not boot into the original Win-7.**

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on the internet.  Specifically, those setting were used to debug systems by **shutting** off cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit the registry offline.

Navigate to this registry Key

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig

in the MSConfig key you will find some sub keys, 
.

[image]
.

Delete any entries in the "startupreg" sub key

Check the Key "state" it should appear like the screenshot below, if any of the dword data values are different, change them back to these defaults.
.

[image]

Once the changes are made, see if it will boot normally.

[Download and use PcRegedit here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-edit-windows-registry-key-values-without-booting-in-windows/)

Comment: I try this method, didn't resolved my issue http://superuser.com/questions/989571/windows-dont-boot-after-set-windows-to-diagnostic-startup-in-msconfig-win7?noredirect=1#comment1364435_989571

Answer (score 1):

In the command Prompt via recovery disc or in built in windows 10,

type 'bcdedit'

Look for the Windows Boot Loader entry that contains an item named 
                     'truncatememory'
Note the identifier for that entry, it may be {default} or {current}, or may be a long GUID like {8eea9b82-d5b1-11de-9d24-80972e3a13c7}
Enter this command:
'bcdedit /deletevalue identifier truncatememory'
replacing identifier with the correct one you noted for that entry.( 'default', 'current' or GUID value ).

Restart the computer

courtesy [techguy.org](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/solved-msconfig-max-memory-problem.929591/)

Answer (score 0):

Dual core does **not** mean that it has two CPU's. And your best option is IMO to get a win-7 disk and do a restore/repair.

Where you get it is another question, getting it from the manufacturer is safest, borrowing one will probably also work or this `Windows 7 (SP1 Included) trial version` from [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Windows-7.shtml) could also work.

Answer (score 0):

you dont actually need the disk.

while booting keep hitting F8 until the the boot menu comes up and select startup repair / recovery and it should fix this problem

if you want to shut off core you should be able to shut them off in your bios but i usually never touch these settings why fix something that was never broke to start with

Answer (score -1):

The fix is really easy here go reboot ur system then keep mashing f8 until u get to the safemode menu then boot ur system using safemode with command promp and then when u get to the command promp type in msconfig and then u change it all back and then restart ur pc and voila
It should work trust me

Comment: It's hard to tweet a good answer from your phone.  Posts on the site need to be in actual English.  When you get to a computer with a keyboard, please turn this into an answer using real words, punctuation, capitalization, grammar, etc.  Thanks.