# Windows don't boot after set Windows to Diagnostic startup in msconfig (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, msconfig

In opened `msconfig.exe` window, `General` tab, I set the `startup selection` to `Diagnostic startup`. After rebooting system windows didn't boot, even in `safe boot`. Operation system is Windows 7. How can i resolve it?

Comment: what was the original problem that made you want it to start up in diagnostic?

Comment: @Kilisi network dhcp delay, after windows boot up, 5 minutes takes to connect to network. On the other hand  in opened msconfig.exe window -> General tab, i can not set it to normal startup, it always changed to selective startup.

Comment: ok, have you tried scf /scannow from a admin command prompt? This should repair msconfig.exe, actually if you move msconfig somewhere else (don't delete it, you might need it) before you do it, it should build you a new msconfig.

Comment: @Kilisi Thanks, command prompt not available, even in `safe mode command prompt` Windows don't load. From where i run the `scf /scannow`? The Windows installation disk is available, also a windows is installed on other partition.

Comment: Can you repair the windows installation using your installation disk? It sounds like your Windows has serious problems, might be better to repair the whole thing then try and fix msconfig

Comment: **@Kilisi forget above my comment** Thanks, Do msconfig.exe is contains of settings? or it is only a executable file? (Windows repair could not resolve the problem)

Comment: It looks like you may have corrupted Windows and/or hard drive. From your other windows installation open a cmd prompt and navigate to the drive and do a chkdsk /r to see if you find errors and fix them automatically, if that doesn't help I would back up my files from the partition and format and rebuild Windows from scratch.

Comment: with this http://superuser.com/questions/339609/changed-boot-settings-in-msconfig-exe-and-now-windows-7-doesnt-boot my problem didn't solved.