# Win 10 Stuck in Safe Mode - Disable Safeboot from Drive

Tags: windows, safe-mode

So, yesterday I tried to update my driver for the graphic card (AMD). It asked me to reboot in Safe Mode, and I did... Now I'm stuck in the limbo of Safe Mode. The windows don't accept my password (either the one I use for the windows or my microsoft account, I use a hotmail account) so I can't get in to change the boot to normal.
I've tried everything I could find online but it doesn't work for me:

- Safe boot with networking - NO
- Use USB to start command prompt and run "bcdedit /deletevaule..." - NO
  U
- Use USB a media installation for Windows and select my primary partition to install new WIndows without deleting my files - NO - I get an error that cannot be used (assuming because is not the only disk, see below).
- Even disconnect the power for a while.

My desktop has two hard drives: the one that came with and a SSD I installed. Both have windows installed. The one is stuck in Safe Mode is the SSD. Using the Boot Manager Option of the computer, I managed to get into my "old desktop" and now I'm copying everything from my SSD to the "old" one so I could reinstall the windows by formatting the disk.

I was just wondering if there is a more delicate (i.e. editing bcdedit or Boot manager on SSD) way to do that instead of copying files back and forth?

[Disk Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ukEf.png)

Comment: It so happens that you have two drives, each with a BCD of its own, so you have to let your BIOS/UEFI know which drive should boot first, but basically, when one is mounted, the other is visible, but may be in read-only mode. Have you tried to discover it in the Network drives? Sometimes that's all it takes for you to copy files back and forth. As for your drive being stuck in Safe Mode, if you can boot from it, you can go to msconfig in the Run box (Windows-R), and make sure the "safe boot" box is unchecked. That should do it. Push come to shove, you delete the "safe boot" entry. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 A freeware called EasyBCD (here: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) could help you sort this out.

Comment: Cant get into Windows to run CMD. I could boot on either drive but the one on my SSD goes to safe mode. How to use easyBCD tho. I downloaded but is useless to me as I dont know/understand what to do with it.

Comment: See if my answer here helps>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/339609/changed-boot-settings-in-msconfig-exe-and-now-windows-7-doesnt-boot/339684#339684

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changed boot settings in msconfig.exe and now Windows 7 doesn't boot](https://superuser.com/questions/339609/changed-boot-settings-in-msconfig-exe-and-now-windows-7-doesnt-boot)

Comment: So, Moab, how do I navigate to the registry of my D drive (since the windows running on C). When I run the regedit, I can't see any "startup" key. Is that because I'm on C drive?

Comment: I manage to load the software hive from D drive but the MSConfig missing. I have only MSInfo

Comment: If you can boot on your SSD, even in Safe Mode, it means there are things you can do to correct its booting in Safe Mode only. It's better than not booting at all. Once in Safe Mode on your SSD, press the Windows and R keys simultaneously, and in the Run box, type "msconfig". In the Boot tab, there should be 1 or 2 lines. Select the 1st, and see if the "Safe mode" box underneath is checked. If so, uncheck it. If it's not already checked, go to the 2nd line in the menu above, and if the "Safe mode" box is checked, uncheck it. Also make sure the "Make those changes permanent" box is unchecked.

Comment: Then reboot. If you managed to do what I suggested in my previous comment, your SSD should boot normally.

Comment: Didier, I can't login on Safe Mode. WIndows dont accept my password.

Comment: You really are making it difficult, you know that? :-) OK, first off, I find it strange that an AMD driver installer would ask you to switch to Safe Mode to install anything. Many users don't know Safe Mode from a hole in the ground, so I don't see a big company like AMD telling you to do this. Are you sure your computer hasn't been infected by some malware? If you can boot from your other drive, can you run a full antivirus scan on the SSD from there, just to be on the safe side? Because if you've got malware and you transfer files from the SSD to the HDD, you're gonna spread the disease...

Comment: I downloaded the autodetector from AMD and asked me to boot in safe mode before installing. Anyway, I'll run an antivirus scan and see. thanks for the tip

Comment: So, disks are clean! . Any other idea?